# R logwarn inserts spaces if more lines, bug?

Tags: r

I have a warning that is in fact 4 warnings:

```
> ParentFunction = function( )
  {
      warning( "warning from parent" )
      ChildFunction1()
      ChildFunction2()
      warning( "second warning from parent" )
      return( TRUE )
  }

> ChildFunction1 = function() {  warning( "warning from child" ) }
> ChildFunction2 = function() {  warning( "second warning from child" ) }

> ParentFunction()
```

It generates:

```
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In ParentFunction() : warning from parent
2: In ChildFunction1() : warning from child
3: In ChildFunction2() : second warning from child
4: In ParentFunction() : second warning from parent
```

so if I would like to log it as warning using logging library from R, I did:

```
if(!is.null(warnings()))
  logwarn(paste("Warning:", warnings(), ":", names(warnings()), sep = " "), logger = "myLogger.Warning")
```

It logs nice, but it has some spaces at the beginning of the last 3 lines:

```
WARNING [2015-08-26 14:50:35] Warning: ParentFunction() : warning from parent
 WARNING [2015-08-26 14:50:35] Warning: ChildFunction1() : warning from child
 WARNING [2015-08-26 14:50:35] Warning: ChildFunction2() : second warning from child
 WARNING [2015-08-26 14:50:35] Warning: ParentFunction() : second warning from parent
```

So I am asking why is that space at the beginning of each line? How should I remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a possibility to eliminate the white space a the beginning of the lines after the firs: using a for loop:

```
if(!is.null(warnings()))
  for(i in 1:length(warnings()))
    logwarn(paste("Warning:", warnings(), ":", names(warnings()), sep = " "), logger = "myLogger.Warning")
```